# String Formatting (Char - Number) MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, formatting

```
A = 45
txt = sprintf('%d.d0 -%d.d0 %d.d0 -%d.d0 %d.d0 -%d.d0 %d.d0 -%d.d0 0. 0.',A)
```

I want to format 'txt' in such a manner that it replaces all %d by the A = 45, however, it only ends up replacing the first term. How do I go about this?

I want the output to be of the form -

```
'45.d0 -45.d0 45.d0 -45.d0 45.d0 -45.d0 45.d0 -45.d0 0. 0.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
txt = sprintf('%d.d0 -%d.d0 %d.d0 -%d.d0 %d.d0 -%d.d0 %d.d0 -%d.d0 0. 0.',repmat(A,1,8))
```